# Excluding % from a Regex number search

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to create a Regex that finds only 2-digit integers or numbers with a precision of 2 decimal points.

In the example string at the bottom, I want to find only the following:

21 and 10.50

Using this expression, 100% is getting captured, in addition to the strings I desire to capture:

`(\d){1,2}(\.?)([0-9]?[0-9]?){1,2}`

I know I need to use `^%` somewhere, but I can't figure out where it goes. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Here's my sample string:**

Earn Up to $21 Per Hour - Deliver Food with !!
 Delivery Drivers work when they want and make great money when they do.

All orders are prepaid, just pick them up and deliver them to hungry diners. No waiting in line or fumbling with receipts and prepaid cards.

It's fast and easy to start working. Get started today.

Apply Now

Why choose ?

More orders than any other takeout platform

100% of our restaurants are official  partners

Competitive pay: Per order fee + mileage + tips

We guarantee an hourly minimum of $10.50/hour*

Create your own schedule & work the hours you want

Comment: Should it capture: 5, 210.50, 10.2, 2.4, 2.50, 10.502 ?

Comment: No. `(\d){1,2}` gets numbers 1 or 2 digits long, `(\.?)` finds a decimal if it's there, `([0-9]?[0-9]?){1,2}` is to get the 2 numbers after the decimal. I'm returning 3 matches (21, 10.50, and 100) from this search. I'm screwing something up in my syntax which is picking up the `%`, which is precisely the one I don't want to capture.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts to your second sentence.  "No" means that neither of given examples should be captured, including the example "5".  "(\d){1,2} gets numbers 1 or 2 digits long" means that it would accept "5", because it has 1 digit.  So should it accept "5", and why or why not?

Comment: "([0-9]?[0-9]?){1,2} is to get the 2 numbers after the decimal." - not true. [0-9]? matches 1 digit or nothing, so [0-9]?[0-9]? matches 0-2 digits, and  ([0-9]?[0-9]?){1,2} matches 0-4 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I'm an infrequent regex user and it seems I've got some more to learn ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word boundaries in your regular expression will grant you a bit more control.

Since word boundaries are a bit strict, we need to introduce an OR condition to address both cases which will satisfy your regex.

```
(\b[\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\b)|(\b[\d]{2}\b)
```

Edit: Try this one,

```
\b[\d]{2}\b(\.[\d]{2})?
```

The first example has a chance to fail as it is order dependent due to the way it short-circuits. This I believe should address multiple cases properly.

Comment: This is order dependent however. Still playing around with it.

Comment: That did it! Me right now--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA Thank you for your solution.

Comment: NP. Do test it a bit to ensure it does not fail for you. But I believe utilizing word boundaries will give you that level of control you were looking for.

Comment: One minor tweak...`\b[\d]{1,2}\b(\.[\d]{1,2})?` I changed it to `{1,2}` instead of `{2}` to capture 1 or 2 digits/decimals instead of just 2

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
(?<!\d)((\d+\.\d\d)|(\d\d))(?!%|\d)
```

[Demo (and explanation)](https://regex101.com/r/idvkia/1)

**EDIT:**

Improved version:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)(?!%|\d)
```

[Demo (and explanation)](https://regex101.com/r/Qx74LV/1)

Comment: That works, too! Thank you, Anmol. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the link to regex101! That site works better than the app I paid for to test regex strings and offers fantastic explanations re: what's going on in a search.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this variant: `(\d{1,}|[\d.])\b(?!%)`
It uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!%)` to exclude digits following by `%` sign.

[Details at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jdfneM/1)